# Set Global UITextField Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-extensions

I'm trying to find a way to globally set the delegate of UITextFields used in my app without having to manually do it for each and every UITextField. My initial thought was to do this using a Swift extension, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Any thoughts...?

What I have now:

```
extension UITextField {
    var delegate : UITextFieldDelegate {
        get {
            return UnoccludedTextFieldDelegate.sharedInstance
        }
    }
}
```

This throws a compile error - `'delegate' used within its own type`

Comment: What about subclassing?